# Add Wordpress shortcode on page without 'get_header'

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, widget, shortcode

I'm trying to add just a wordpress plug-in widget to a page. No blog, no template or anything, just the widget. I can get the widget to load properly, but it's pulling in a bunch of styles that are over-riding my current CSS. Is there an easy way do this without having to create a custom page?

```
<?
  require( '../blog/wp-load.php' );
  get_header();
?>
..//..
<? 
  do_shortcode('[my shortcode]'); 
?>
```

I tried removing the `get_header()`, but the widget won't pull any data. Is there a way to just get the Wordpress functionality running right?

Comment: did you create the widget? or is it a ready-made widget?

Comment: but the page is custom, yes? meaning you built it from scratch?

Comment: ok.  Find the js and css requirements of the widget and add it to the page manually.  This will remove the requirement for the `get_header()` function.

Comment: how would i get those? should I inspect a page that has the widget running properly? or are they listed somewhere?

Comment: ok, it seems to be working, the styles are all messed up within the widget, but it's loading. Feel free to add answer if you want. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad it worked for you.
Find the js and css requirements of the widget and add it to the page manually. This will remove the requirement for the get_header() function.

Comment: I ended up viewing the source of a page that was loading it properly, and just stripping out the js/css generated. Not sure if there's a better way to do it, but it's working. Thanks!

Comment: happens to alot of us.  some widgets come with their own css which is set by the widget, others go through the wordpress object system.